# CVCalendar by Mozharovsky dates do not show

Tags: ios, swift

I am in need of a calendar view for my app. I have decided to use CVCalendar via pod file. However the issue is I can get the days to appear (Sun-Sat) but not the dates (1-19...).

In my Controller file I have:

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class ViewController: UIViewController, CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
}


func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
    return CalendarMode.MonthView
}

func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
    return Weekday.Sunday
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

here is the full code

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class TabEventsViewController: UIViewController, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate, CVCalendarViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewCalendar: CVCalendarView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuViewCalendar: CVCalendarMenuView!

    func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
        return CalendarMode.MonthView
    }

    func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
        return Weekday.Monday
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        viewCalendar.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
        menuViewCalendar.commitMenuViewUpdate()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */



}
```

here are some tips:

1. make sure you set delegates (2 for calendar view and 1 for calendar menu)
2. make sure your uiview does not have negative horizontal spacing value

Answer (score 0):

- Did you hook up the delegate for the calendar (date) part? [Delegate setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6Re.png)

  - You're delegating the rendering to your ViewController
  - You need to drag to the yellow view controller nub.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done what Phil.Ng said, and it still doesn't work, there might be something wrong with constraints. Try adding:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too until I found [this](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/issues/258) answer on the GitHub issues. If you change your horizontal constraints on your storyboard to positive values, it should work.